# how to create multiple mysql db services and view the respective databases in a single phpmyadmin service with docker-compose

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin

I want to create multiple database services and in turn view the databases in a single phpmyadmin service with docker-compose.

The docker-compose file is here below

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  dbone:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: dbone
    ports:
      - "8080:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sakila
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - TZ=Africa/Lagos
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/db/mysql/dump/2-create-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql
      - persistent_1:/var/lib/mysql
    command: ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci", "--skip-character-set-client-handshake", "--default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password"]
  dbtwo:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: dbtwo
    ports:
      - "8090:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql_json_db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - TZ=Africa/Lagos
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/db/mysql/dump/mysql_json_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql
      - persistent_2:/var/lib/mysql
    command: ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci", "--skip-character-set-client-handshake", "--default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password"]
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - done
      - dbtwo
    ports:
      - "8070:80"
    environment:
      - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=0
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
volumes:
  persistent_1:
  persistent_2:
```

As seen above, dbone and dbtwo are the database services I want to be made available for phpmyadmin service. In order to do so, I set mysql as the host name of MYSQL_HOST for dbone and dbtwo, respectively and also set mysql as the host name of PMA_HOST for the phpmyadmin service.

Some how I feel the service names such as dbone and dbtwo should be the MYSQL_HOST names, respectively for both containers. But if I set MYSQL_HOST=dbone and MYSQL_HOST=dbtwo for dbone and dbtwo containers respectively, I find it difficult to set the PMA_HOST for the phpmyadmin container.

My docker-compose file has been run with the following command

```
docker-compose up --build
```

and I have tried to access localhost:8070 which opens phpmyadmin but attempt to login with username: user and password: test, fails and shows the following:

```
Cannot log in to the MySQL server

mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed:  Temporary failure in name resolution

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Please I need help on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Remove `PMA_HOST=mysql` (you don't have a MySQL container called `mysql`) from the environment config for PMA. When connecting specify the host as `dbone` or `dbtwo`. 8080 and 8090 are typically used as alternates for port 80 (http). Perhaps 3307 & 3308 would be more _"normal"_. You have a typo in your dependencies for the `phpmyadmin` container - `done` instead of `dbone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works now with the following updates

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  dbone:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: dbone
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=dbone
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sakila
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - TZ=Africa/Lagos
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/db/mysql/dump/2-create-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql
      - persistent_1:/var/lib/mysql
    command: ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci", "--skip-character-set-client-handshake", "--default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password"]
  dbtwo:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: dbtwo
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=dbtwo
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql_json_db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - TZ=Africa/Lagos
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/db/mysql/dump/mysql_json_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql
      - persistent_2:/var/lib/mysql
    command: ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci", "--skip-character-set-client-handshake", "--default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password"]
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - dbone
      - dbtwo
    ports:
      - "8070:80"
    environment:
      - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=0
      - PMA_HOSTS=dbone,dbtwo
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
volumes:
  persistent_1:
  persistent_2:
```